# Expose Oracle ATP

Tags: oracle

Does anyone have experience with exposing Oracle's ATP functionality via API for integration to Salesforce? Our customer's version of Oracle (11i) doesn't support it as standard, but curious if anyone has found a solution for this previously.

Comment: It's documented here https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-data-warehouse-cloud/user/ords-autonomous-database.html#GUID-E2E921FF-2D80-4E32-9660-28506D10BADB and I have a blog on this here https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2019/10/everything-you-need-to-know-about-ords-on-autonomous-database/

Comment: also, oracle 11gR2 is definitely supported by Oracle REST Data Services - you can build APIs to ingest or publish data from your database to be used by your Salesforce environment